# Changing line managers

Tags: united-kingdom, manager, new-manager, furlough

Im in a strange situation where my line manager has been furloughed and as a result im temporarily being put under someone else in the department who I know, have worked with before and respect. And I really like the direction my temporary one is going.

Context

I have been thinking for a while about changing anyway as I don't feel my main line manager is giving me the career support I crave. This is for a mixture of reasons, distance, disciplines, I feel like I get nowhere and he has his own LM issues of his own. So far my temporary one has given me alot of support, structure and a path to get to where I want to in a fairly short space and I'd very much like to see where this goes. Which I do have 3 weeks minimum until my actual manager is back.

My worry is I don't want my current (furloughed) manager to take this personally, its just a different style that my temp one provides I feel is working for me and I value him as a friend as well as a boss. I appreciate everything he has done for me thus far, he is generally a great mentor and helps me with any small problems/anxieties I may have. But in terms of career I don't think I have progressed very far under him since joining the business and I don't really have alot of confidence in him where as I feel I can/do with my temporary one.

My questions are:

Has anyone ever had this before and how did you handle it?

How did you structure the conversations to approach all parties involved?

Comment: Officially I don’t know, but I have seen it happen.

Comment: Any down votes, please follow guides and say why. If I don’t know why, I can’t learn or adapt the question so it is better.

Comment: Don't worry about downvotes. Some people on here downvote everything about interpersonal relationships.

Answer (score 3):

I respectfully suggest you wait until your company can bring people back from furloughs before you pursue this question.

You can certainly tell your replacement manager you like working for them. But the timing, in the middle of a health crisis, is very likely not so good to try to ask for a change like this.

Comment: It’s fairly early days with the new temp manager and my actual manager is off for minimum 3 weeks. I’d have to wait until we’re out of the worst of this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach your temporary line manager first and discuss this with him. He'll probably know if staying with him is an option.

If staying with him *isn't* an option then there's a good chance your furloughed line manager will never even know that the conversation took place.

If staying with him *is* an option then I'd play that by ear. It's quite possible that that wouldn't be a conversation you'd even need to have with your furloughed line manager - that your current temporary one could have that conversation on your behalf. In this scenario whether or not you want to talk to your old / currently furloughed manager would be your prerogative. It might be strategically advantageous to do so in the long term or it might not - it really depends on your situation.

Comment: I feel like I should talk to my furloughed manager about it if it works out with my temporary one to protect the relationship.